# ASP.NET Server.Mappath problem from inner folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application where in my APP_Code folder I have a class. In that I have the following code to read the content of an XML file which is in my root folder:

```
XmlDocument xmlSiteConfig = new XmlDocument();
xmlSiteConfig.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../myConfig.xml"));
```

My Root folder is having several folders with nested inner folders for some. From the first level of folders when I call the piece of code in the Appcode class, I am able to load the XML file correctly since the path is correct. Now if I call the same piece of code from an inner folder, I am getting an error. If I change the code to the below it will work fine

```
xmlSiteConfig.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../../myConfig.xml"));
```

How can I solve this? I don't want to change the file path for various calls to this code.With what piece of code I can solve the issue so that the program will load the XML file irrespective of the calling position.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's in the root folder, use this:

```
Server.MapPath("~/myConfig.xml")
```

This will work from any directory.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your path string with a tilde (~) - this represents the root of the website:

```
xmlSiteConfig.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/myConfig.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

the method System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("") is to get the root path of the web app.
so System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../myConfig.xml") is to get the father path of the web app
it is wrong if your file is not here.
you can use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/path") instead.

in other hand,you can use "~" to mean the root path in some asp.net control.

Answer (score 0):

Does Server.MapPath("~/xmlFile.xml") work for you?  The ~/ tells the .NET application to always start from the application root.  If your XML file is in a sub folder (not where you are calling the function but the actual physical file), then you would use server.mappath("~/myfolder/xmlFile.xml").

Comment: David M and iAn type faster than I do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.MapPath("~/MYXML.xml")
```

In this "~" means, root directory.
If you want to find in any sub directory then you should give path e.g,

```
Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyXml.xml")
```