# What is wrong with this file path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, file-upload, server.mappath

Hai guys,

I have two folders called CSVLoad and Forms... I have an aspx page inside forms folder which has a fileupload control. I save my uploaded file to my CSVLoad folder i gave the following path

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("CSVLoad//" + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

I am receiving file not found exception...

```
Could not find a part of the path 
'F:\WebSites\Payroll\Forms\CSVLoad\Employeesdata.csv'
```

CSVLoad folder is outside Forms folder (ie) both are root level folders of my application

**Answer :**

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/CSVLoad//" + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

from one of previous SO questions [ASP.NET Server.Mappath problem from inner folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158530/asp-net-server-mappath-problem-from-inner-folders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path does not start with a slash, then it returns a path relative to the current directory that the page is in, in this case Forms I assume. If you want it to map a path relative to the root of your application, then you should prefix a slash on the path and use:

```
Server.MapPath("~/CSVLoad/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```